# Nifi container running but not accessible via UI

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I am very new to docker and Nifi so please understand if my question doesn't sound refined.

When I downloaded Nifi from official apache nifi website and fired it up, it was accessible via http://localhost:8443/nifi

But when I created a docker container using the following command

```
docker run -itd -p 8433:8080 --name nifi apache/nifi
```

it runs without a problem but it's not accessible via web UI

When I used

```
docker logs d7 | grep "JettyServer"
```

2022-07-07 23:17:13,334 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
2022-07-07 23:17:13,334 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer https://d723418f https://d723418f16d5:8443/nifi

above message was shown, which to my understanding it means that Nifi is running.

I have tried

-localhost:8433

-host IP:8433

-bridge network IP:8433

but none of those work.
Is this possibly because of the update on version 1.14.0 since it accesses UI via https rather than http and requires ID and password now ?
Or am I just missing something very simple?

Thank you all for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `nifi` listening only `8443` port (and using HTTPS connection)

If you want to connect using unsecure HTTP, you need to set HTTP port:

```bash
docker run -itd -p 8443:8080 -e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080 --name nifi apache/nifi
```

In this case HTTPS connection will be disabled and you will be able to connect with `http://localhost:8443/nifi` instead of secured HTTPS

＊ It is not possible to activate both `8080` (HTTP) and `8443` (HTTPS) connection at same time. You have to edit container entrypoint
script (`/opt/nifi/scripts/start.sh`) to activate both connections

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for ! Thank you for the clear explanation

Comment: my hangup was starting with docker-compose, which doesn't seem to work well when using the http/8080, but it all seems fine when launched directly (docker run...)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the port setting to 8443:8443 and added /nifi to the URL and it started working