# How to connect via http instead of default https on nifi docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I am currently running latest versions Nifi and Postgresql via docker compose.
as of 1.14 version update of Nifi, when you accesss the UI on web it connects via https, thus asking you for ID and Password every time you log in. Its too cumbersome to go to nifi-app.log file and look for credentials every time I access the UI. I know that you can change the setting where it keeps https as the default method but I am not sure how to do that in a docker container. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nifi container running but not accessible via UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72905286/nifi-container-running-but-not-accessible-via-ui)

Comment: I explained how to connect via http in your previous question. What is actual problem? "How to connect via http" or "how to remove validation"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some env like AUTH in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi)
You can find the full explanations [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Version1.14.0)